# Parameterize test data filename - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have multiple test CSV files (approx. 20 files with a million records (just one column of IDs) in each file) in a folder. I want to run a performance test using this data.

To loop through the files, I have made progress but I am stuck at one issue. First I will explain what I have accomplished so far and then the issue I am running into.

1. Added a BeanShell sampler (script is below) under Thread Group. 
   It creates file variables with file paths as values.
   e.g. `file_1 = /Users/Code/JMeter-Campaign/data/file_1.txt`

```java
import java.io.*; 

File fileDir = new File("/Users/Code/JMeter-Campaign/data"); 
File[] fList = fileDir.listFiles(); 

int counter = 1; 

for (File file:fList) {
    if (! file.isHidden()) {
        vars.put("file_" + counter, file.getAbsolutePath());
        log.info("file_" + counter + "=" + vars.get("file_" + counter));    
        counter++;
    }
}
```

2. Add `ForEach` controller to loop. Fields and values are below.

> Input variable prefix : file
>   Start index for loop : 0
>   Output variable name: USER_FILE
>   Add _ before number - checked

3. Added Beanshell Preprocessor as a child of `ForEach` controller. 
   Converts vars in props.

   ```
   props.put("UserFile", vars.get("USER_FILE"));
   ```
4. Added CSV Data Set config as a child of `ForEach` controller.

> Filename : ${__P(UserFile,)}
>   Delimeter: ,

First, I am testing a simple scenario - 3 files (file_1, file_2 and file_3) with 1 record in each.

It's looping through all 3 files (debugged using log.info, debug sampler, view results tree) however the data is coming from the last file only. 
So for file_1, data is from file_3

Also observer in the jmeter.log, jmeter.services.FileServer always points to the 3rd file.

Is there a better way to parameterize test CSV files? I want to my run the test with all records in the first file and then second file and so on. This will prevent server side caching.

Comment: I have edited your post to help make it more readable. Please look it over and make sure it makes sense, and further edit it if I have made it less clear.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot parameterize CSV Data Set Config this way as file paths are being populated during test tree loading. All you can do is to define a property via i.e. `-J` command line argument like

```
jmeter -Jpath=/some/path.csv -n -t ....
```

and use [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function like `${__P(path,)}` in the CSV Data Set Config. But this way you won't be able to iterate.

So I would suggest considering [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function which is evaluated during its execution time hence it may contain variables.

See [Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions) User Manual chapter and [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series for more detailed information on above and other JMeter Functions.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thank a lot for replying.

Comment: Hi Dimitri ,Can u send sample test Plan for this,